# Property 'id' not found on type com.spring.schoolmanagement.model.Subject

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I'm trying to put two objects in my JSP view but while getting the value by getter is working fine and while referring the value by property of the object throws error.

JSP Code Snipet is:

```html
<div class="row">
     <div class="box">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
            <hr><h2 class="intro-text text-center">Manage Subject</h2><hr>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
   <c:url var="addAction" value="/data-entry/subject/add" ></c:url>
   
   <form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="subject">
   <table>
    <c:if test="${!empty subject.name}">
    <tr>
     <td>
      <form:label path="id">
       <spring:message text="ID"/>
      </form:label>
     </td>
     <td>
      <form:input path="id" readonly="true" size="8"  disabled="true" />
      <form:hidden path="id" />
     </td> 
    </tr>
    </c:if>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <form:label path="name">
       <spring:message text="Name"/>
      </form:label>
     </td>
     <td>
      <form:input path="name" />
     </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <form:label path="description">
       <spring:message text="Description"/>
      </form:label>
     </td>
     <td>
      <form:input path="description" />
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="2">
      <c:if test="${!empty subject.name}">
       <input type="submit"
        value="<spring:message text="Edit Subject"/>" />
      </c:if>
      <c:if test="${empty subject.name}">
       <input type="submit"
        value="<spring:message text="Add Subject"/>" />
      </c:if>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table> 
   </form:form>
   <br>
   <h3>Subject List</h3>
   <c:if test="${!empty subjectlist}">
    <table class="tg">
    <tr>
     <th>ID</th>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Description</th>
     <th>Edit</th>
     <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${subjectlist}" var="subject">
     <tr>
      <td>${subject.getID()}</td>
      <td>${subject.getName()}</td>
      <td>${subject.getDescription()}</td>
      <td><a href="<c:url value='/admin/subject/edit/${subject.getID()}' />" >Edit</a></td>
      <td><a href="<c:url value='/admin/subject/remove/${subject.getID()}' />" >Delete</a></td>
     </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </table>
   </c:if>
  </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Model Class:

```html
package com.spring.schoolmanagement.model;

public class Subject {
 private int id;
 private String name;
 private String description;

 public void setID(int id) {
  this.id = id;
 }

 public int getID() {
  return this.id;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }

 public String getName() {
  return this.name;
 }

 public void setDescription( String description ) {
  this.description = description;
 }
 
 public String getDescription() {
  return this.description;
 }

 @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "{ID=" + id + ",Name=" + name + ",Description=" + description + "}";
    }
}
```

**Controller Class:**

```html
package com.spring.schoolmangement;

import java.util.Locale;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.spring.schoolmanagement.dao.SubjectDAOImpl;
import com.spring.schoolmanagement.model.Subject;

/**
 * Handles requests for admin specific pages.
 */
@Controller
public class AdminController {

 private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

 
 
 @Autowired
 private SubjectDAOImpl subjectService;
 
 
 /**
  * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
  */
 @RequestMapping(value = {"/admin/", "/admin"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
  return "admin-dash-board";
 }

 
 @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/student")
 public String student(Model model) {
  return "admin-student";
 }
 
 @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/subject")
 public String displaySubjects(Model model) {
  model.addAttribute("subject", new Subject());
  model.addAttribute("subjectlist", this.subjectService.getAll());
  return "manage-subject";
 }
 
 @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/subject/edit/{id}")
 public String course(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {
  model.addAttribute("subject", this.subjectService.getById(id));
  model.addAttribute("subjectlist", this.subjectService.getAll());
  return "manage-subject";
 }
}
```

Please suggest where I'm making the mistake.

Comment: method setter `setID` is not correct as per getter/setter policy. It should be `setId(String id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your getter/setter method from:

```
public void setID(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getID() {
    return this.id;
}
```

To

```
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}
```

Your Bean is missing naming convention and should follow [JavaBean (read pdf section 8.8)](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/) naming convention.